# LinkedStateMixinでsetStateのコールバックを指定する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React.jsの`setState`メソッドにコールバックを渡すと、Stateの更新が終わった時にそのコールバックを実行してくれます。
しかし`setState`を抽象化したLinkedStateMixinにはコールバックを指定する方法を見つけられませんでした。
どうにかしてLinkedStateMixinを利用しつつsetState後の処理を渡すことはできないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedStateMixin`の実装を見てみると、

- https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.12.2/src/addons/link/LinkedStateMixin.js#L34
- https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.12.2/src/core/ReactStateSetters.js#L59

ここに`setState`があります。
コールバックを外から指定できそうにないですね。

状態変化後に何らかの処理を行う他の手段としては、[`componentDidUpdate`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate)を利用する方法が考えられます。

Comment: あるいは、単純なMixinのようなので、自分でコールバックを指定できるものを作ってしまうのも有りかもしれません。

Comment: たしかに`LinkedStateMixin`ではコールバックを指定できそうにないですね……。

`componentDidUpdate`を利用したところ目的の処理は書けました。
ありがとうございます。

個人的にはあまりライフサイクルメソッドを書きたくないので、`LinkedStateMixin`の今後に期待しています。